# Validation of Contact Form 7 with custom form action

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, add-filter

I am using Contact Form 7 to collect data (text only) that I need to send to an external url with `post`.
In order to do so, I set up a custom filter with `add_filter`

```
    add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
    function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
    {
        return "myexternalurl";
    }
```

and disabled AJAX with `define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);`

However, doing so resulted in loosing the fields validation, since the CF7 validation function in so called anymore. My new action replaces the CF7 action (which was performing the check):

- Form without changes: validation: OK (with or without AJAX); the form code looks like
  `<form action="/mypage/#wpcf7-f4426-p4427-o1" method="post">`
- Form with custom action: validation not performed; the form code looks like
  `<form action="newurl" method="post">`

Is there a way to setup a custom action without loosing the CF7 validation process?

Comment: This is not the way to solve this kind of problem.  You should hook into the form submission process in the backend after it has been successfully submitted, collect the data and POST it to your external URL from the server using PHP.